# Not getting satisfactory results with Loop and variable when using Python with Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Code:

```
import mysql.connector
con=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="project")
mycursor=con.cursor()

check="SELECT * FROM seat_status WHERE S_code=5"
cmd=mycursor.execute(check)
for x in cmd:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Project CS\CS Project.ipynb Cell 4 in <cell line: 7>()
      5 check="SELECT * FROM seat_status WHERE S_code=5"
      6 cmd=mycursor.execute(check)
----> 7 for x in cmd:
      8     print(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I'm making a CS project (movie booking system);
I already made a 'book any seat' program, what i want now is to check the availability of the seat before booking.
Have already created a table with columns (s_code and s_status, B-Booked NB-Not Booked)
So what I want is for Python to return me the 'B' or 'NB' and then use if else etc.

Edit:
After following @buran suggestion, it worked but the output wasn't satisfactory. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QRjN.png)

Comment: `cmd=mycursor.execute(check)` should be `mycursor.execute(check)`, i.e. it works in-place. Then iterate over cursor or use `mycursor.fetchall()` in the loop

Comment: @buran it worked but the answer wasn't satisfactory, please check the edited code

Comment: Because X is a tuple. You will always get tuples, even if it is one element tuple. All this is in the docs, which is the first place to look for an answer.